# How to get only sha512sum of a file in Ubuntu 14?

Tags: ubuntu, checksum, sha512, ubuntu-14.10

I'm trying to assign `sha512sum` of a `tar.gz` file to a variable in shell in ubuntu 14.

I tried `sha512sum` mentioned here https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/sha512sum.1.html

But it's printing both `512sum` and also the `file_name`.

But I'm only looking for the sum in this case. Are there any flags that I can pass? I didn't find any such in the manpage for `sha512sum`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe it to cut and use the first field.

```
sha512sum  FILENAME  | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

Options don't seem to be there.